# resizing plots generated using R.Net causes application to crash

Tags: c#, .net, r, r.net

I'm using R.Net library.

This is my sample code:

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); 
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
engine.Evaluate("cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)");
engine.Evaluate("plot(cars)");
```

And the chart appears but when I try to resize the window with it my .Net application crashes/

Does anyone of you know this issue and how to handle that?

Comment: What is interesting when I do it not from console application but from winforms application on buttonClick everything works fine. It has to be something with threads

Comment: Interesting. On a recent Linux/Mono stack I get a lack of refresh (blanks out) on resize. Not a crash, but still an issue. I have created https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/153. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: This is a console app? I couldn't recreate it in WPF. You mentioned a console app and threading, is that what you have, R code on a separate thread in a console app?

Comment: The plot window that shows up is the default Windows device provided by the R project and is internal to R. For people unfamiliar with R, there's been surprises with calling R code from outside the dispatcher thread in WPF and then R tries to create/manipulate the default device.